# Asus intel i7, intel hd graphics 5500, trouble with slight more demanding gaming fix?

Tags: gaming

I have a pretty standard modern computer, an asus with i7 and intel hd graphics 5500. With i7 isnt that suppose to be a pretty strong running cpu, yet i have trouble running minecraft with shaders on 15 fps.
Im formatting it to make it fresh, but howcome it cant handle slightly more demanding settings, is there any tweaking or software i can install to make it legitametly faster in running games (basically i just want it to run minecraft with shaders smoothly :/).

Thanks

Comment: The problem isn't the i7, it's the Intel HD graphics. You're just not going to get that to go any faster than 'slow'. Only chance you have is if it's actually a dual-card machine, or if a desktop, buy a dedicated graphics card.

Comment: @Tetsujin its a laptop, are there external gpu's i can attach , or would it be possible to install on the motherboard,appreciate the help

Comment: You can get external GPUs, though I've no experience with any of them & to recommend one would turn this into a 'shopping' question which would be off-topic. Try Googling "laptop external gpu" for articles & products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A laptop with only the on-chip Intel HD graphics is always going to be at the low-end for graphics & gaming performance. They were never really designed to throw 3D models around & though recent ones are getting better, they're a long way behind the power of a dedicated card.

If your machine doesn't already have a second card, the probability is that is wasn't built to take one. You would be best to check with the manufacturer, just in case there is a retrofit option.

Alternatively, you'd need to research for an external GPU; there are many available & I cannot recommend one as I have no personal experience, nor would it be on-topic for Super User.
Googling 'laptop external GPU' will bring up a lot of hits for shopping as well as informational resources on how to choose one.